# Counting the number of numbers

Tags: mysql

I have the following numbers:

> 0,37,38,39,40,43,54,55,56,57,60,67,68,71,76,79,81,84,91,97,105,111,116,117,37,38,39,40,43,54,55,56,57,60,67,68,71,76,79,81,84,88,91,97,105,111,116,117,118,119,37,38,39,40,43,54,55,56,57,60,67,68,71,76,79,81,84,88,91,97,105,111,116,117,120,121,124,130,139,143,151,155,157,167,172,182,187,189,190,195,200,201,227,228,230,232,233,234,235,236,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,246,247,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,289,290,316,331,341,342,343,344,351,369,370,396,399,403,404,405,406,407

I want to know how many numbers there are. For example...

```
SELECT COUNT (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
```

...should return 10 numbers. Is there a way I can do this using MySQL?

Comment: I wonder it there's some correlation between the number of digits and the number of commas.

Comment: Are you looking for digits (_0123456789_) or are you looking for number (_0, 37, 38 are the first three numbers in your example_)?

Answer (score 3):

Use combination of `length` and `replace` functions.

```
mysql> SELECT length(replace('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0', ',', '' ));
+--------------------------------------------------+
| length(replace('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0', ',', '' )) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                               10 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.33 sec)
```

And however, you have to handle other characters if any, present in the string.

And let me also hope that you are asking number of digits but not number of CSV's in the string.

Comment: SELECT LENGTH(REPLACE('12,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0', ',', '' )); it returns me 10 but there are only 9 digits

Comment: You should understand the difference between the *digits* and *numbers*.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think you are really looking for:

```
SELECT length('43,54,55,56,57,60,67,68,71') - 
       length(replace('43,54,55,56,57,60,67,68,71', ',' ,'')) + 1
```

The above would return `9`.

If I were to use

```
SELECT length(replace('43,54,55,56,57,60,67,68,71', ',', '' ));
```

It would return `18` which is not correct unless you are after the unique number of chararacters other than the commas.

Comment: this gives the number of commas.

Comment: But it really counts numbers. ...Now, it is correct)

Comment: @user2202257: You should change your requirements to *count of numbers* from *number of digits*

Comment: You are welcome but no thanks is needed.  A simple upvote and and marking the answer as accepted would suffice.

Comment: @Ravinder yes u r correct. i was confused how to frame question. thanks